# How can I detect and convert text encoding?

Tags: apache-flex, encoding, air

Some text (or html) document from web is not encoded as UTF-8, so I want to convert encoding of text document to UTF-8.
Do you have any clues for dealing with text encoding?

And I found that, when application draws  element with encoding-broken text (such as "¿©¼º ½̾ ±â"), the application is often killed with alert dialog "adl quit unexpectedly". How can I make my application more endurable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash Player uses `UTF-8` by default. You can change this via [`System.useCodePage`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#useCodePage) but it still will use only **ONE** encoding (depends on the client machine).

If you want to load text with arbitrary encoding, you should load text as `ByteArray` and then parse it manually into string. Not sure if there are some libs for this.

P.S: If you get a chance - convert all your incoming data to UTF-8 on the server or somewhere - not on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could solve this problem on the client using ByteArray.